# MVC application and the API controller

Tags: api, model-view-controller, architecture

**My understanding**

Architecture of a basic MVC web application (in simplified manner)

```
(MVC View -> MVC Controller) -> Biz layer -> Data Access Layer -> DB
```

Then, I have to support mobile devices and provide them with specific pieces of information. So I create appropriate API controllers only to expose the required data.

```
Mobile device -> API Controller -> Biz layer -> Data Access Layer -> DB
```

**Queries and doubts**

I have seen (or heard) the below being suggested:

```
(MVC View -> MVC Controller) -> API Controller -> Biz layer -> Data Access Layer -> DB
```

OR

```
MVC View -> API Controller -> Biz layer -> Data Access Layer -> DB
```

The basic idea is that we expose the entire application functionality (Biz Layer) over services. The MVC application will then use the API controllers.

**Question 1: API creation**

As of this point, I would create an API controller in my MVC web application only if I have some data to be exposed as a service (for mobile devices or the like). Am I  missing some other criteria?

**Question 2: API usage**

Above, calling the API controller from the MVC view seems fine, although not necessarily needed. But why call the API from a MVC controller? (Seems wrong to me. The MVC controller can talk to biz layer directly)

**Question 3: API advantage**

Data returned from API will be encoded as JSON and sent to client. However we can always return JSONResult from a MVC controller for an MVC View. Are there advantages to use an API controller in a purely MVC application?

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to start with the last question

> Data returned from API will be encoded as JSON and sent to client.
>   However we can always return JSONResult from a MVC controller for an
>   MVC View. Are there advantages to use an API controller in a purely
>   MVC application?

From functional perspective you could do anything with MVC controllers from what you can do with API Controller but with more coding. I used to know a few projects with API built on top of MVC controllers but that was before API controllers were announced. So if your controllers mostly return HTML (rendered view) it doesn't make sense to build an API controller to return JSON to populate a dropdown. However if it's a single page application with rich client (doesn't matter mobile or not) or just an API to be used by third party clients, your choice should be API controller. I suggest reading [this article](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-api-vs-asp-net-mvc-apis/) to learn more on when you should use API controllers.

> Above, calling the API controller from the MVC view seems fine,
>   although not necessarily needed. But why call the API from a MVC
>   controller? (Seems wrong to me. The MVC controller can talk to biz
>   layer directly)

You are right it's definitely wrong. One more layer which does nothing but maps browser request into an API one and then maps let's say JSON result into HTML or just passes it along doint nothing. Besides there's a redundant HTTP call which could be a huge problem from performance and maintanance perspective.

> As of this point, I would create an API controller in my MVC web
>   application only if I have some data to be exposed as a service (for
>   mobile devices or the like). Am I missing some other criteria?

I think I already answered that above. So if you just need to expose some stuff for mobile I think you can either use the same controllers but with different views(mobile version) or just build separate UI layer (Views and controllers) for mobile. I don't see why you would want to go for API controllers unless your mobile UI is a classical single page application. Also if your goal is to expose all functionality for mobile in the long run please take a look at the reponsive design. This way you will have the same views and controllers for all devices.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @nikhil pinto is my answer helpful?